# Linear gradient is not working in Outlook

Tags: javascript, html, css, email, gradient

I know this is a very basic question but I have tried many StackOverflow solutions but nothing worked for me.

This is the HTML content which I am using.

```html
<html>
<style>
  div:after {
    content: "\A";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(216, 38, 38, 0.7) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(216, 38, 38, 0.7)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(216, 38, 38, 0.7) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(216, 38, 38, 0.7) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(216, 38, 38, 0.7) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(216, 38, 38, 0.7) 100%);
    /* W3C */
  }
</style>
<div style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%);background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ *//* background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); */ /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 100%); /* IE10+ */background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(216, 30, 30, 0.7) 100%);  /* W3C */">
  <p>This is heading</p>
</div>

</html>
```

It is working on Gmail but not in Outlook.

Screenshot of the Gmail

[image]

Screenshot of the Outlook

[image]

Please correct me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Not work with outlook - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/css-gradients/

Comment: Although CSS Gradients not supported as mentioned, you could still use an image to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Outlook does not support linear-gradients.
Outlook, especially for Windows, primarily supports basic CSS.

See Campaign monitor: 
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/css-gradients/